# PDO get data from database

Tags: php, select, pdo, while-loop, fetch

I started using PDO recently, earlier I was using just MySQL.
Now I am trying to get all data from database.

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
$getUsers->fetchAll();
if(count($getUsers) > 0){
    while($user = $getUsers->fetch()){
        echo $user['username']."<br/>";
    }
}else{
    error('No users.');
}
```

But it is not showing any users, just a blank page.

Comment: What is `error(...)`? Make sure error reporting is on....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `PDO` method [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array/result-set, which you need to assign to a variable and then use/iterate through that variable:

```
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user['username'] . '<br />';
}
```

**UPDATE** (missing `execute()`)
Also, it appears you aren't calling the [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method which needs to happen *after* you prepare the statement but *before* you actually fetch the data:

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
$getUsers->execute();
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();
...
```

Comment: @user1791971 If you do `var_dump($users);`, after the `fetchAll()`, what does it display?

Comment: do you have error checking on and displaying: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');` to the top of the script

Comment: @user1791971 Ah, I re-read your post; you're also missing a call to `execute()`. I've updated my answer with the relevant info.

Answer (score 7):

This code below will do what you are asking for:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
$sql->execute();
while ($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $result['username']."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is missing a call to [`execute()`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) after [`prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). After your prepared statement is executed you can get the array of records using [`fetchAll()`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC');
$getUsers->execute();
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();

// Then in your presentation logic you can use the following code to display the data:
if ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user['username']."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    // Whatever your requirement is to handle the no user case, do it here.
    echo 'Error: No users.';
}
```

However, in you example you are not passing any variable data to the query and you only execute it once, which defeats a purpose of having prepared statement. You should use prepared statements if you need to have variables in your SQL, for example:

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?');
$getUsers->execute([
    $_GET['user_id']
]);
$user = $getUsers->fetch();     // get single user by unique id
```

If there are no variables then you can simply use [`query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method.

```
$users = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC')->fetchAll();
```

If you do not need to fetch all records at once, you can simply loop on the statement with `foreach`:

```
$getUsers = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE ? ORDER BY id ASC');
$getUsers->execute([
    '%' . $_GET['search'] . '%'     // search for username with wildcards
]);

foreach ($getUsers as $user) {
    echo $user['username']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I think `fetchAll()` should only be used if you are incorporating one of PDO's clever/magical [fetching modes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall) or if the processing of the result set is being done in another layer of the application.   In other words, if you are going to immediately iterate the result set as a "standard" structured result set, don't use `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa I disagree. I understand your point, and I do so in my own code, but I believe that in my answers I should strive to show the separation of application and presentation logic. The data should be fetched into PHP structures and the PDO statement should not be exposed to the presentation logic. Maybe I did not make this distinction clear in this answer due to brevity, but it was my goal. The `foreach` loop is used to display the data, not process the resultset.

Comment: If you are going to instantly handle specific rows, then I do not recommend fetchAll().  This creates a pile only to pick through it one by one.  I like the last snippet best.