# How to SELECT from database for each index in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have the PHP code below which returns an array of the contents of the table passed through `$_GET['table']`.

```
$getTable = "SELECT * FROM " .$_GET['table'];       
$tableExe = $auth_table->runQuery($getTable); 
$tableExe->execute();
$tableArray  = $tableExe->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I add the following which will select each index within the array and which value I want to get:

```
$lvl1_pos_1 = $tableArray[0]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_2 = $tableArray[1]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_3 = $tableArray[2]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_4 = $tableArray[3]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_5 = $tableArray[4]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_6 = $tableArray[5]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_7 = $tableArray[6]['user_id']; 
$lvl1_pos_8 = $tableArray[7]['user_id'];
```

Now I would like to find a way where I can easily collect the `user_name` associated with each of the `user_id's`. The result with the user_name will need to be outputted like below:

```
<div><?php echo $lvl1_pos_1; ?><?div>
<div><?php echo $lvl1_pos_2; ?><?div>
<div><?php echo $lvl1_pos_3; ?><?div>
<div><?php echo $lvl1_pos_4; ?><?div>
.....
.....
<div><?php echo $lvl1_pos_8; ?><?div>
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this easily?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO get data from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183579/pdo-get-data-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `foreach()` loop to iterate your tables data-rows like this and capture `user_id` and `user_name` easily like below. I've used another array called `$simplified_array` to capture `user_id` as key and `user_name` as value.

```
$simplified_array = [];
foreach($tableArray as $key=>$value){
  simplified_array[$value['user_id']] = $value['user_name'];
}

//check what it contains, debug purpose only.
print_r($simplified_array);
```

The above `$simplified_array` contains **user_id** as key and **user_name** as value so you can easily iterate it to create the **div** as you wish.

Comment: How could I check if the `user_id` is empty or not for all of my variables?

Comment: You can try like this `if(empty($value['user_id'])){}`

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the $TableArray variable you have. 
*(By the way, this was to be a comment but my reputation doesn't allow me to post comments)*
Since the $TableArray is an array, maybe you mean how to loop through it. Maybe something like:

```
 <?php
foreach($TableArray as $item):
?>
<div><?php //echo "Your data here"; ?></div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Also the closing  are formatted wrongly in your code