# How to modify my PHP and HTML code to download file from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am a beginner in programming. I want to make user to be able to download a file which was uploaded and saved in MySQL database. I have searched a lot for this problem but i got very confused and can't yet grasp the logic. This is the code i reached:

```
$filequery = "SELECT file,file_name,file_mimo FROM ticket WHERE id=:ticketID";
$filestmt = $connection->prepare($filequery);
$filestmt->bindParam('ticketID',$ticketID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$filestmt->execute();
$filestmt->bindColumn(1,$file,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$filestmt->bindColumn(2,$filename,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$filestmt->bindColumn(3,$type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$filestmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
readfile($file);
```

So what should i add  to my PHP code and what HTML code to write to present a button to download that file? (answering in code will be much appreciated)

Comment: not recommended to store files in db, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560485/6293599

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with? The button will be standard get or put it in form for a post. Your program also does not output any data.

Comment: If you fetch the column you get the data. Is `$file` a path or actual file data? Please [check the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) before smashing around with random functions.

Comment: $file is an actual file data

Comment: Can you tell me in code what to modify in my code?

Comment: readFile expects you to provide it a filename so it can open the file from disk. Like tadman said, if you'd read the documentation you would know this. So if `$file` already contains the file data, as you say, then just echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$file` already contains the data then you should be able to just dump it out as-is:

```php
echo($file);
```

Note that `readfile()` expects a *file path* as an argument, so feeding it in a  binary file as an argument is pure nonsense.

Since you're learning, mistakes will be made, that's understood, but this one was entirely avoidable. PHP has fantastic documentation on every single function you might use, so always check you're using a function correctly before going through with it. When learning a new programming language it's pretty much expected you'll have the documentation open at all times so you can check things as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You should keep files on your server. For this, you must first upload the file to the server and then save the download link in the database. Then you need to print the link in the database to the download button. To upload files securely, you should definitely check their type and size.

[A simple file upload example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

[This link contains a simple example for insert item to database](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert)

[Here is a simple code on how to print data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183579/pdo-get-data-from-database)

Comment: Please, **do not link to w3schools**. It's the "WikiHow" of programming and has caused considerable damage, something that we need to spend a lot of time repairing here.

Comment: You are right about this, but such sites explain many topics in detail and encourage learning by experiment, so I chose to give this. If he really wants to learn, he has to research and learn by trying. These are just learning tools. In addition, these sites are more useful for beginners as they explain the subject more simply. He can also learn it from the official PHP site but this will be very difficult for the first level.
Still, thank you for your criticism.I'll be more careful about this

Comment: This site is all about learning and it's to be encouraged with any resources that help. The problem is w3schools does more harm than good. Where practical, try and link to existing Stack Overflow answers. Another thing to note is if your answer is mostly just links, it should probably be a comment. Answers are expected to include working solutions as in code.